# Grouping rows in data frame by factor level

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame like following:

```
  `df$A`    `df$B`     `df$C`
   BCG        2          4
   ACD        5          1
   DFA        4          3 
   ACD        4          2
   BCG        1          4
   DFA        3          5
   BCG        5          4
```

Assuming that my `df$A` is factor, how can I group the data frame rows based on factor level in `df$A`. In short, I am expecting the result like following:

```
  `df$A`    `df$B`     `df$C`
   BCG        2          4
   BCG        1          4
   BCG        5          4
   ACD        5          1
   ACD        4          2
   DFA        4          3
   DFA        3          5
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: `df[order(df$A),]` I think is what you are looking for. If this is not working, you can rename the variables in your data.frame, `names(df) <- LETTERS[1:3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example,

```
dfc <- data.frame(a = rep(c('a', 'b'), 5), b = 1:10, c = 2:11)
```

To order `dfc` by the factors, you can simply perform:

```
dfc[order(dfc$a),]
```